# Can't get Nest.PropertyName to be considered for nested

Tags: elasticsearch, nest, elk

I have a type of entry in elastic that is made of some imbricated properties like

```
{
    "_source":
    {
        "pipeline_version":1.7,
        "agent":{
            "hostname":"SFPWEW11616",
            "id":"a1df2f4e-6dde-43fd-8af6-b3726124fdf7",
            "type":"winlogbeat",
            "ephemeral_id":"78be9770-dab9-4c56-a67e-b1a372a2f899",
            "version":"7.5.1"
        }
    }, [...]
}
```

I'm trying to get my POCO to represent a  flatten vie of this object. According to what I found in the documentation, I tried doing something in the like of

```
Friend Class ElasticEventLogEntry
  <Nest.PropertyName("agent.hostname")>
  Public Property AgentHostName As String
  [...]
End Class
```

But no matter what I try, the value is always empty. I've seen some other posts using the NestedAttribute attribute but from what I could find, this is only useful if we want to also create nested objects in our POCO structure which isn't my case. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to do what you're trying to do, at least not without writing your own JSON serialization for your `ElasticEventLogEntry` type and hooking up with [`JsonNetSerializer`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/custom-serialization.html#_jsonnetserializer).

A better approach would be to model `ElasticEventLogEntry` differently

```vb
Public Class ElasticEventLogEntry
    <DataMember(Name:="pipeline_version")>
    Public Property PipelineVersion As String
    Public Property Agent As Agent
End Class

Public Class Agent
    Public Property Hostname As String
    Public Property Id As String
    Public Property Type As String
    <DataMember(Name:="ephemeral_id")>
    Public Property EphemeralId As String
    Public Property Version As String
End Class
```

Then agent hostname will be deserialized to `.Agent.Hostname`

Comment: OK, thanks. That was unfortunately what I expected. Sad that we can't use dot notation in the PropertyName attribute.

Comment: What is weird with this behaviour is that if you set PropertyName with the dot notation on the property, it is used for querying but not for deserializing.

Comment: It's valid JSON to have object field names contain a dot, so `{"agent.hostname":"dot-hostname","agent":{"hostname":"agent-hostname"}` is valid - how should a serializer handle this at deserialization? And if POCOs have attributes containing dots, how should a serializer handle this at serialization? The serializer uses the property names as specified, including dots.

Comment: @RusaCam But this is an Elastic specific attribute and Elastic does not play well with dotted filed names so the attribute could "easily" enforce this and do the correct translation for the serializer behind the scene.

Comment: It really scares me that NEST doesn't support this out of the box.